# Is it possible to execute some database query that user can write that queries from android application?

Tags: android, sql-server

I want to create an android application that can run SQL Query to my SQL Server Database. 
Here is my basic idea:

1. I create an android application with 1 textbox and 1 button.
2. Users can write the query that they want (e.g. INSERT INTO..,
   UPDATE.., DELETE.., or EXEC [store procedure]) in the textbox.
3. Then users press the button to execute that query to run in my SQL
   Server Database.

What I've made so far is an Android Application using phonegap + jQuery Mobile and I can get some data from my WCF Service with JSON that connect to my SQL Server, but now I want to run some query that I write from android application and run it to my database. Is it possible? Can you tell me the recommendation tutorials? Thanks :)

Comment: Rather than ask for tutorials, you ought to ask a specific question that can be given an answer. Show your work, show your research, and then explain in detail what's stopping you from doing something.

Comment: @nil okay, thank you for your advice :) I'm sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done.

1. Create an Android application with an *EditText* and a *Button*.
2. Users can type the query to run (e.g. INSERT INTO.., UPDATE.., DELETE.., or EXEC [store procedure]) into the *EditText*.

You could do this like below to make it more user friendly.

1. Give users some options for Insert/Update/Delete via buttons.
2. Add a *Spinner* with all the table names.
3. If the user select a table name, show some _EditText_s for all the columns you need to get a value from the user.

Also you can make separate methods to call accordingly, with required inputs. It will be less complex more user friendly.

I don't know if it Is makes any sense.

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer, it opens my mind to start it. well the user want to write custom query and free to write it so I can't make it with button as you said on your answer. and I'm not make it yet, but now I want to start make it. then I will update or create my question if I get stuck. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yas You can dear ..

i just success with select data from the sql server and i am sure very soon i am defiantly reach to the insert update and delete too.

for now you can also follow this tutorial which is actually in different language but you can go through the android and eclipse is working on english so just follow my steps.

1st make one project and download jtdc driver from this link but make sure the jtdc driver version is "1.2.7"

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.2.7/
put this jar file in libs folder and write click on libs folder and build-add jar file and take that from libs folder and press ok which is reference library for sql server never forget this.

Now just follow my code bellow.

Make a xml file "sqlservermain.xml"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SqlServerMain" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="SQL SERVER" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_enter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/edt_name"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/edt_name"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Enter" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lst_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn_enter"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_enter"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp" >
    </ListView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lst_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

then make one another xml file which is "sql.xml" file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

now make one java file which is "sqlservermain.java" file.

```
package com.sqlserver;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SqlServerMain extends Activity {
        private Button _btnenter;
    private EditText _edtval;
    private ListView _lstname;
    private Connection connect;
    private SimpleAdapter AD;

    private void declaration() {

        _btnenter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_enter);
        _edtval = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
        _lstname = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_name);

    }

    private void Initialization() {
        declaration();
        _edtval.setText("Select Value");
        connect = CONN("user","pass","db","server");
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private Connection CONN(String _user, String _pass, String _DB,
            String _server) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String connURL = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            connURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + _server + ";"
                    + "databaseName=" + _DB + ";user=" + _user + ";password="
                    + _pass + ";";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.d("Error", se.getMessage());
            // Toast.makeText(this, "Error : " + se,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ce) {
            Log.d("Error", ce.getMessage());
            // Toast.makeText(this, "Error : " + ce,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
            // Toast.makeText(this, "Error : " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return conn;
    }

    public void QuerySQL(String COMANDOSQL) {
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
            rs = statement.executeQuery(COMANDOSQL);

            List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
            data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                datanum.put("A", rs.getString("Table Field 1"));
                datanum.put("B", rs.getString("Table Field 2"));
                data.add(datanum);
            }
            String[] from = { "A", "B" };
            int[] views = { R.id.textView2, R.id.textView1 };
            AD = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.sql, from, views);
            _lstname.setAdapter(AD);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sqlservermain);
        Initialization();
        _btnenter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                QuerySQL(_edtval.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And now its time to give some permission in "AndroidManifest.xml"

which is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

anjoy thats it for retriving.
the data.